# Facebook and Website SEO

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, facebook

I am the webmaster of a website, and one issue that I'm having is getting our home website to appear above our Facebook page. Are there any Google Webmaster Tools or meta data tricks I can employ to make our main website rank higher than our Facebook page?

Comment: Your site its probably very recent? in that case, this issue would be fixed with time; if its not so recent.. good  question :P

Comment: There are no tricks. This is no different than trying to outrank anyone. Improve the SEO for your pages using the tips in the linked-to question. Getting more links to your home page using your website name in the anchor text is the best way to start.

Comment: Have you set the website in the facebook page's info?  Its under "Edit Page" -> "Update Page Info".  Then at least the facebook page would link back to your site.  Google might use that as a signal, and users should be able to get where they need to go from it.